# Open a file directly from browser

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I want to open an aplication when I click on a link in Internet Explorer, actualy the link is point to a file and it will download, if I click on the downloaded file my aplication is launch and it loads the file. But I want to launch the aplication without "click" from the downloads folder, just "clicking" on the internet explorer (hope I explain myself).

In short, the behaviour I want is like clicking on a pdf link, it shows a menu to choose which app you want to launch (or directly open a pdf viewer)

Actualy I did this on the manifest, but this just allow my to launch from a folder:

```
 <Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
      <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="SALO">
        <uap:DisplayName>SALO</uap:DisplayName>
        <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          <uap:FileType>.salo</uap:FileType>
        </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
      </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
    </uap:Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

Thanks

Comment: It's a *long* time since anyone thought it was sensible to let a web browser launch arbitrary applications without any user intervention.

Comment: May be I didn't explain it right, but the behaviour i want is quite common. When I click on a pdf link, it shows a menu to choose which app I want to lauch (or directly open a pdf viewer)